# R, get longitude/latitude data for cities and add it to my dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, latitude-longitude

I would like to get longitude/latitude data for the cities in my dataframe and add as 2 columns in my frame. I'm new to R and I do not know how to do it.
Could someone help me on this

My frame:

```
> data <- read.xlsx("example_city.xlsx", 1)
> data
        City Country
1  Stockholm  Sweden
2       Oslo  Norway
3       Rome   Italy
4       Rome   Italy
5  Stockholm  Sweden
6  Stockholm  Sweden
7      Paris  France
8      Paris  France
9    Hamburg Germany
10     Paris  France
11     Paris  France
```

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote you, but you really need to have made some hash at it first, before asking here. Showing us your data is a good start. What have you specifcally tried? Have you search engined any of this? e.g. *"geolocating cities in R"*.

Comment: Here you go... http://www.r-chart.com/2010/07/maps-geocoding-and-r-user-conference.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With reference to your original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936263/use-ggplot2-to-plot-cities-on-a-map

```
# data 
cities <- sort(c(rep('Stockholm', 3), 'Oslo', 'Rome', 'Rome', 'Paris', rep('Bonn',10), 'Paris', 'Paris', 'Stockholm'))

# get frequencies
freq <- as.data.frame(table(cities))
library(plotrix)
freq$Freq <- rescale(freq$Freq, c(1,10)) # c(scale_min, scale_max)

# get cities latitude/longitude - kindly provided by google:
library(ggmap)
lonlat <- geocode(unique(cities)) 
cities <- cbind(freq, lonlat)

# get matches between names {maps} names and EU country names
library(maps)
eu <- c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", 
        "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", 
        "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", 
        "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", 
        "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom")
warning("No matches in database for ", paste(setdiff(eu, map_data('world')$region), collapse=", ")) 
europe <- map_data('world', region=eu)

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(europe, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="white", colour="black") +
  xlim(-20, 40) + ylim(25,75) +
  geom_point(data=cities, inherit.aes=F, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=Freq), colour="red", alpha=.8) + 
  geom_text(data=cities, inherit.aes=F, aes(x=lon, y=lat, label=cities), vjust=1, colour="red", alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much...This will really help me with my original dataset!!

Comment: Good luck, @jonas. There will surely be more tripping hazards other than tedious country name matching.