# Lat-long using geocode from ggmap

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

I am getting an error while getting `latitude-longitude` for cities using [ggmap](/questions/tagged/ggmap) package and `geocode` function.

```
library(ggmap)
# get frequencies
mycities<- as.character(Chennai$City1)
freq <- as.data.frame(table(mycities))
library(plotrix)
library(ggmap)
freq$Freq <- rescale(freq$Freq, c(1,10)) # c(scale_min, scale_max)
geocode(freq$mycities[1])
dput(head(freq))
```

And the data structure is

```
structure(list(mycities = structure(1:6, .Label = c("Alamanda Rs", 
"Aluva", "Ambasamudram", "Ambattur", "Ameerpet", "Amreli", "Anakapalle", 
"ANATHAPUR", "Anekal", "Aranthangi", "Aravakurichi", "Ariyalur", 
"Asifnagar", "Bagalkot", "Banaganapalle", "Bandlaguda", "Bangalore", 
"BANGALORE", "Bangalore North", "Bangalore South", "Bapatla", 
"Belgaum", "Bellary", "BELLARY", "Bhadrachalam", "Bhadravati", 
"Bibinagar", "Bidar", "Bikkavolu", "Bilgi", "Bobbili", "Buchinaidu Kandriga", 
"Chengalpattu", "Chennai", "Chennai City Corporation", "Chikodi", 
"Chillakur", "Chincholi", "Chinglepet", "Chittapur", "Chittur", 
"Chityal", "CHOUTUPPAL", "COCHIN", "Coimbatore South", "Coonoor", 
"Cuddalore", "Dachepalle", "Davangere", "Dharapuram", "Dindigul", 
"Doddaballapura", "Duggirala", "Egmore", "Ernakulam", "Erode", 
"Etcherla", "Ettayapuram", "Ghanpur (Mulug)", "Gokak", "Gokavaram", 
"Gooty", "Gopalapuram Mandalam", "Gopannapalem", "Gulbarga", 
"Gummidipundi", "Guntur", "Haliyal", "Hassan", "Hindupur", "Hoskote", 
"Hospet", "Hosur", "Humnabad", "Huvinahadagali", "Huzurnagar", 
"Hyd", "Hyderabad", "HYDERABAD", "Iluppur", "INDRAKARAN VILLAGE", 
"Jamkhandi", "Jogipet", "KAKINADA", "Kakinada (Urban)", "Kamalapuram", 
"Kamareddy", "Kanakapura", "Kanayannur", "Kanchipuram", "Kariapatti", 
"Karkala", "Karthikappally", "Karunagapally", "Karur", "Karwar", 
"Khairatabad", "Khammam", "KOCHI", "Kondapalli", "Koppal", "Kothakota", 
"KOTHUR", "Kovvur", "Kozhikode", "Krishna", "Krishnagiri", "Kunigal", 
"Kunnathunad", "Kurnool", "Lalgudi", "Laveru Mandal", "Luxettipet", 
"Maddur", "Madurantakam", "MAHESWARAM MANDAL", "Malur", "Mamidikuduru", 
"Manachanallur", "Manapparai", "Mandapeta", "Mangalore", "MANGALORE", 
"Mangapet", "Mannargudi", "Manugurq", "Manuguru", "Mayiladuthurai", 
"Medikonduru", "Melur", "Mettupalayam", "Mettur", "Miryalguda", 
"Muddebihal", "Mudhol", "Mukundapuram", "Musheerabad", "Muthukur", 
"Mysore", "MYSORE", "NA", "Nagapattinam", "Naidupeta", "Nalgonda", 
"NALGONDA", "Nampally", "Nanguneri", "Nanjangud", "Narsapur", 
"Narsipatnam", "Nedumangad", "Nedungadu Commune Panchayat", "Nelamangala", 
"Nellore", "Nilakkottai", "Ongole", "Palakkad", "Paloncha", "Palwancha", 
"Paravada", "Paravur", "Patancheru", "PATHANAMTHITTA", "Pedagantyada", 
"Peddapalli", "Peddapuram", "Pennagaram", "Perambur Purasawalkam", 
"Periyakulam", "Pollachi", "Pondicherry", "Ponneri", "Prathipadu", 
"Pusapatirega", "Qutubullapur", "R.c.puram", "Radhapuram", "Raichur", 
"Rajahmundry (Urban)", "Ramagundam", "Ramanagara", "Ramanathapuram", 
"Ramdurg", "Ranasthalam Mandal", "Ranebennur", "RANGA REDDY", 
"Rangareddy", "Renigunta", "Saidabad", "Saidapet", "Salem", "Samalkota", 
"Sandur", "Sangareddy", "Sankari", "Sathankulam", "Sathyamangalam", 
"Secunderabad", "Sedam", "Shahapur", "Shaikpet", "Singanamala", 
"Sira", "Sirpur (t)", "Sivakasi", "Somwarpet", "SRIKAKULAM", 
"Sriperumbudur", "SRIPERUMBUDUR", "Stn. Jadcherla", "Sullurpeta", 
"Suryapet", "SURYAPET", "Tada", "TADA", "Tadipatri", "Tallarevu", 
"Tambaram", "Tanuku", "Tanuku (mdl)", "Thanjavur", "Tharangambadi", 
"Thimmajipet", "Thirumalairayan Pattinam Commune Panchayat", 
"Thiruvananthapuram", "Thiruvidaimarudur", "Thondamanadu", "Thoothukkudi", 
"Tindivanam", "Tiruchendur", "Tiruchengodu", "TIRUCHIRAPALLI", 
"Tirukkoyilur", "Tiruklalikundram", "Tirumalagiri", "Tirunelveli", 
"Tiruvallur", "Tiruvannamalai", "Tiruvidamarudur", "Tumkur", 
"Tuni", "TUTICORIN", "Udupi", "Uppal", "Uppalaguptam", "Vaikom", 
"Vedaranyam", "Vedasandur", "Veepangandla", "Vemula", "Venkatachalam", 
"Vepada", "Villianur Commune Panchayat", "Vinjamoor", "Virudhachalam", 
"Virudhunagar", "Virur", "VISAKHAPATNAM", "Vontimitta", "Walajapet", 
"Yerraguntla", "Zaheerabad"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1, 
1, 1, 4.33333333333333, 1.16666666666667, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

i am getting error like

> Error in geocode(freq$mycities[1]) : is.character(location) is not
>   TRUE

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: The workflow of your code is hard to follow. What exactly is the data you posted relative to your code? Is it what you started with, or what you ended with? Please be more clear about your questions when posting.

Comment: `geocode(as.character(freq$mycities))` That should work. `freq$mycities` was a factor. I'm gonna call this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937682/r-trying-to-find-latitude-longitude-data-for-cities-in-europe-and-getting-geocod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R trying to find latitude/longitude data for cities in europe and getting geocode error messege](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937682/r-trying-to-find-latitude-longitude-data-for-cities-in-europe-and-getting-geocod)

Comment: ##Example from stackoverflow:
                                                                                                        mycities1<- c("Hyderabad","Chennai","Bangalore","Cochin","ARNHEM","London")
str(mycities1)
geocode(mycities1[1])..i have created this simple vector with city names and used the geocode command on the same.. still it is throwing error like.    Warning message:
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Hyderabad"

Comment: Cyrus, I have referred the same example which you have suggested. but the thing is even with the same example i am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because the google API changed and thats what its using primarly which will result in this error:

> geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

If you change the `source` to `dsk` and convert to character it should work:

```
geocode(as.character(freq$mycities[1]), source = "dsk")
```

> Information from URL :
> http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Alamanda%20Rs&sensor=false
>
> lon lat
> 1 -54 -30